# Strangely slow: what happened when TakeWhile met AsParallel?

Tags: c#, linq, plinq

I know that wrong usage of linq may cause lower performance but this time it's too strange.

When i call "AsParallel.TakeWhile.AsParallel.ForAll", it's **MUCH** slower than "AsParallel.TakeWhile.ForAll". Can somebody explain why?

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Action<int> doNothing = i => { };

            var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Enumerable.Range(1, 100).AsParallel().TakeWhile(m => m < 10)
                .ForAll(doNothing);
            var ticks1 = stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;

            stopwatch.Restart();
            Enumerable.Range(1, 100).AsParallel().TakeWhile(m => m < 10)
                .AsParallel() // spend much more time with this AsParallel 
                .ForAll(doNothing);
            var ticks2 = stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;

            Console.WriteLine("ticks without AsParallel: {0}\r\n with AsParallel: {1}", ticks1, ticks2);
            //ticks without AsParallel: 87956
            //with AsParallel: 6688708
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would also be interesting to see the performance of the same query without any parallelism at all: Enumerable.Range(1, 100).TakeWhile(m => m < 10).ForAll(doNothing);

Comment: Except that ForAll is not a method of Enumerable, but of ParallelEnumerable only...

Comment: But ForAll is essentially just a parallel version of foreach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call AsParallel, the framework starts to divide the work into smaller parts which can be scheduled on different cores. These parts later needed to be merge back into the result. This causes some overhead.

You have already made the query parallel by the first "AsParallel" and when you call it the second time the partition happens again, causing even more overhead but giving you no performance boost.

See [*Understanding Speedup in PLINQ*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997399%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.